# How to automatically assign Long Term Retention (LTR) policy to new databases

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a large number of databases running on a SQL Database Server in Azure. We're trying to automate some basic functions, in this case, setting the LTR policy on all new databases, so there's no chance of one slipping through the cracks and not getting set.

Is there anyway to automatically assign LTR policies?

I've found lots of ways to assign it (through the Portal, through Azure CLI, Powershell, etc.), but they all require doing it either en masse or to a single databases, and all require manual execution.

Is there anyway to tell Azure to apply a default to new databases automatically, so we don't have to do anything manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, trying to help you out.

Maybe you could create an **Event Grid System Topic** for the source type: Microsoft.ResourceNotifications.Resources.

[image: EventGridSystemTopic]

Follow by a Event Subscriptions that calls an Azure Function PowerShell

[image]

In your Azure Function Powershell, you'll need to parse the parameter that's passed: $eventGridEvent

I THINK you can want to filter for provider/Microsoft.Sql

Good luck!